# encode request.query in express

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote a simple API to return requset.query in response.

Sample Url:
http://localhost:8082/redirect?requesttype=click&id=79992&redirectto=http://localhost:8081/redirect?name=john&id=123

This returns following response,

[image]

but on passing encoded Url things are working as expected(screenshot attached),

http://localhost:8082/redirect?requesttype=click&id=79992&redirectto=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8081%2Fredirect%3Fname%3Djohn%26id%3D123

[image]

But our API is getting utilized by various customers, is there any method in express.js where I can automatically encode the Url and serve the request as expected.

Comment: Do you use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) ?

Comment: yes..using body parser